# is it possible to run gatling and selenium test togethter

Tags: java, selenium, load-testing, gatling

I am new in load testing.
I want to use gatling for testing. seems to be based on scala ( which runs over JVM)

I want to use some old selenium tests ( java based )
Is it possible to make a java project and run both ?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/load-testing-selenium-vs-jmeter-vs-other-tools

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, of course! Just make sure you don't have any library version collision. If that happens, you'll have to isolate in different project/modules.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest option is using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool which can launch [Gatling](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Gatling/) and [Selenium](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/) tests using single simple [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) configuration file like:

```
---
execution:
- executor: gatling 
  scenario:
    script: /path/to/your/GatlingTest.scala
    simulation: tests.gatling.BasicSimulation
- executor: "selenium"
  scenario:
    script: "/path/to/your/SeleniumTest.java"
```